# python trouble getting code to work

Tags: python

***update* so it seems like no matter what i do or type it asks
what would you like to add?
 instead of doing the other options it just keeps asking this 
it should only be asking this if the user types a**

this is a 2 issue thing im having and the main original post is here

[How to debug errors in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50080888/9693182)

but the bigger issue im having is i cant get the bottom half of my code to work
it just ignores the inputs given to it and continues to add them to the list

```
#.....
      elif user == "d" :
         listdelete = input("what item do you want deleted")
         list.remove (listdelete)
      elif user == "p" : # prints the list 
       print (list)
      elif user == "x" :  # exits the program 
       print ("good bye")
print ("!!!!!!that is not a choice!!!!!!")
   #right now everything is being called through a single procedure
print (option())
```

and on the bottom here is going to be the entire code  sorry for pasting the entire code on the bottom here but i thought it would be easy to understand the whole issue if i showed the whole code and then the section thats not working since its all under one procedure

```
list = []
def option() :
   print ("(a) -to add item ")
   print ("(d) -to delete item")
   print ("(p) -to see items on your list")
   print ("(x) -to exit ")
#above just prints out user options with a input after
   user = input("please select a choice")
   if user == "a" :
      item = input("what would you like to add? ")
      list.append (item)
   # next im going to ask if they would like to add another item 
   more = input(" would you like to add something else? yes or no")
   while more == "yes":
      if more == "yes" :
         item = input("what else would you like to add? type b to back ")
      if item == "b" :
            print (option())
      else :
            list.append(item)
      elif more == "no" :
         print (option()) 
#.....
      elif user == "d" :
         listdelete = input("what item do you want deleted")
         list.remove (listdelete)
      elif user == "p" : # prints the list 
       print (list)
      elif user == "x" :  # exits the program 
       print ("good bye")
print ("!!!!!!that is not a choice!!!!!!")
   #right now everything is being called through a single procedure
print (option())
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code which still has flaws and exploits the mutability of the list datatype but does work as you would expect it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


def AddElement(collection):
    elementToAdd = input("What would you like to add: ")
    collection.append(elementToAdd)

    return collection


def DeleteElement(collection):
    print("You have the following items:", collection)
    elementToDelete = input("What item do you want deleted: ")
    for elements in collection:
        if elements == elementToDelete:
            collection.remove(elements)
    print("You have the following items left:", collection)

    return collection

def WriteMenu():
    print("(a) -to add item")
    print("(d) -to delete item")
    print("(p) -to see items on your lst1")
    print("(x) -to exit")

    return True

def option():
    WriteMenu()
    UserInput = input("Please select a choice: ")
    while UserInput:
        if UserInput == "a":
            AddElement(collection)
        elif UserInput == "d":
            DeleteElement(collection)
        elif UserInput == "p":
            print(collection)
        elif UserInput == "x":
            print("Good bye!")
            break
        WriteMenu()
        UserInput = input("Please select a choice: ")
    else:
        print(collection)

#right now everything is being called through a single procedure
collection = []
option()
```

Comment: alright so right now delete, print and exiting does not work and im sorry i started programing like 4 weeks ago so im gonnna do some bad mistakes im trying to learn from them

Comment: @CodingNoob I updated your program. You can test it and makes changes if you like. Maybe you can learn a thing or two.

Comment: @CodingNoob also if a answer was helpful please remember to upvote or/and accept the answer. If not please provide feedback so that it is possible to impove.

Comment: im curious why did you put a argument in there? and how bad was my code this was my first project

Comment: @CodingNoob I would prefer a fully Object Oriented methodology. Though functions should be as generic as they could be allowing you to reuse them in different projects. That said if you pass the requirements to the function the function can act more flexible. As to your code quality: I can't answer that. Code quality depends on the use-case. However from a professional standpoint your code tends to be fragile ( changing one things breaks another ), is not tested ( so it is neither good code and does not scale ) and so on. Your progress however is \_\_absolutely\_\_ normal. Programming is hard.

Comment: any tips i shoud watch out for in the future

Comment: @CodingNoob programming really is too complicated to give you an easy answer on that. There are hundreds of pitfalls and problems. For what I tend to see beginners get wrong is that they have very fragmented wisdom of the core features of the language. If you want to take programming serious you should not just learn whenever you have a specific problem but rather continous and for example guided with a book or a tutor. Will you have to search the next problem up or can you solve most problems by your own. If you can't you should get back to the basics and try to master them.

Comment: im currently still learning the basics im a student right now and this was a assignment for class

i thought the code i had was decent for what i learned in 4 and a half weeks  it worked up untill the end when i added in a few bit of lines  and then the rest stoped working when i tried to while loop it 

i noticed in your code it was alot neater and more organized then mine  and instead of mine having all in one procedure and in a loop untill ended 
you had yours in multiple separate procedures under one argument

Comment: if i could just ask you one more thing if you dont mind? what do you mean by fragmented wisdom. and what is the importance of a argument?  for example in your procedures all with different names  
you had collection as a argument in all of them 
was this used to call upon them  as one thing

Comment: @CodingNoob If you want to learn how to cook and watch one youtube video that explains to you how to cook a specific recipe - what are you likely to end up with? You probably learned many different techniques you just know enough of to use them for that recipe. To know them from "ground-up" is what you want if you want to master them.

Comment: @CodingNoob And towards the importance of arguments: The arguments are like a box. The function is able to process the contents of the box in the same manner. If you make your functions generic enough you can put many different things in those boxes. `collection` became the argument of our function to make it possible to give you the possibility to let the user manage alternative lists without creating new functions that manage lists.